# Uploading to test.pypi

Tags: python, python-3.10, testpypi

I followed the steps at [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and managed to successfully upload the example package. However, when it came to uploading my own larger package I get the warning/error:

```
python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: __token__
Enter your password: 
Uploading mypackage_j21-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
WARNING  Retrying (Retry(total=9, connect=5, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol     
         (_ssl.c:2426)'))': /legacy/                                                                                                                                                
WARNING  Retrying (Retry(total=8, connect=5, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol     
         (_ssl.c:2426)'))': /legacy/                                                                                                                                                
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 224.1/224.1 MB • 01:40 • 2.3 MB/s
```

I've now tried this on both Linux Mint 21 and Win10 and get the same. On the sample tutorial example, when that finished it provides a link to the newly uploaded package, but in this case after the "100% complete", there is no link, and rightly so because it doesn't exist. But in itself this is confusing because it states 100% complete, but it's telling lies.

Although, it responds with a warning I suspect this is in fact an error and is consistent.

I even opened the Terminal As Administrator on Win10 and got exactly the same response.

Has anyone else seen this before and know what is wrong?

Thanks.